# Server.MapPath on a remote server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, server.mappath

I have 4 front end servers.  Only one of those servers (lets call it server A) has a bunch of images and documents.

Now, I have this line of code that works in a single front end environment

HttpContext.Server.MapPath("/temp");

Now, what I'd like to do is refer to the mapped path of the /temp folder not of the server that the user hits from the load balancer but the mapped path of the /temp folder of server A.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'd be better off storing the resource folder location in config of the website and using [`System.IO.Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx) to map paths.

Comment: @SachinKainth: Not until you provide all the parameters in your question. Besides, I'm knocking off home in 5 mins.